# Errors when running Spring Roo

Tags: spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have installed the Spring Roo 1.2.0.RELEASE version but i Can't run.
My JDK_HOME and JAVA_HOME Home system variables are properly set.
The ROO_HOME is set too.

Apparently Felix can't load some bundle, but I couldn't identify what.

When I try to run Roo, the errors above happen. I have not found the error log archive, so I captured the prints.

[image]

[image]

Someone got this error on this version?

The MS-DOS output [here](https://gist.github.com/1670899).

Comment: It's hard to read your screenshot.  Can you attach the entire stack trace (if the trace is long, then you can use http://pastebin.com/.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1670899

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

This is what was occurring:

https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-1931